# Water leaks on passengers side feet when raining

Tags: subaru, forester, water-leak

I have a 2008 Subaru Forester.  When it rains, water drips onto the passenger side floor from underneath the glove box. It doesn't matter if the car is moving or parked. In fact it seems to drip more water when it is parked.

At my last service the mechanic ran a hose over the car for a while and couldnt see where it was coming from. He suggested talking to a windshield repair guy.

I phoned a windshield repair guy and they said it's most likely coming in from the roof racks and I should talk to a panel beater.

I don't want to take it to a panel shop and spend money on those guys looking for an issue when I could do it myself first.  Just wanted to see if anyone had any recommendations on where to look.

Comment: Do you have a sunroof?

Comment: No, I have no sunroof

Comment: Then a clogged drain in the air plenum at the base of the windshield is the first place I'd look.

Answer (score 4):

Had a similar problem, open the hood and look under the wipers. If you have a plastic tray under the wipers, sometimes the drain hose gets clogged with trash and needs to be cleaned. In my case it poured under the glove box until fixed.

Comment: Thank you for the insight.  I ran a hose over the windshield again, making sure I didn't get any on the roof and it did start to leak.  However, I was getting a ton of water coming from the wheel well.  Would this indicate that the drain hose is working?

Comment: On a Dodge Caravan you can actually see the drain hose in the front, I don't know about other brands. You may be able to see it in the wheel well. Try google for a picture or location if possible. This still does not rule out a window leak

Answer (score 0):

[image: this little stick was clogging the drain hole on my Moms Subaru]

This was what I found clogging the drain hole on my Moms Subaru.